# PHP how to add classname or filename/filepath before echo messages

Tags: php, logging, echo

In my project i have echos in a lot of different locations. It will be pain to edit all of them. I wish to add [CLASSNAME/FILENAME/FILEPATH] before echo, like:

echo result:
NOW:

```
message: test1, asd!
error: file does not exist!
```

AFTER:

```
[SuperClass] message: test1, asd!
[OtherClass] error: file does not exist!
```

(if way using classname is not possible (static casts) i would like to use filename or filepath where echo is used)

Comment: The only solution I see is to modify the PHP source code and recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

See [Magic constants](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

For **class** is:

```
 __CLASS__  

The class name. The class name includes the namespace it was declared in (e.g. Foo\Bar). Note that as of PHP 5.4 __CLASS__ works also in traits. When used in a trait method, __CLASS__ is the name of the class the trait is used in.
```

For **file** is:

```
__FILE__    

The full path and filename of the file with symlinks resolved. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned.
```

For **path**:

```
__DIR__ 

The directory of the file. If used inside an include, the directory of the included file is returned. This is equivalent to dirname(__FILE__). This directory name does not have a trailing slash unless it is the root directory.
```

This is an **example** of how to use magic constants to include classes without writing each class in each echo:

```
echo “[”.__CLASS__.”] message: test1, asd!”
```

Comment: How does that answer OP's question?